# Hive metastore configuration

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I configured hive with MYSQL as repository. When I start the hive server using my standard user (infa_hadoop) it is giving me an error "`cant connect to metastore using the URI provided`".
But if I login as `root` and start the hive server it starts well.

**command used:**

```
hive --service  hiveserver
```

But when I tried to execute the ETL job (informatica) it is giving me the Access control exception!

```
Error : 
Function [INFASQLExecute] failed in adapter [/u01/app/informatica/plugins/dynamic/hiveruntime/libhive.so] with error code [-1].
FnName: INFASQLExecute -- execute(). SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 12, cause: FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.RuntimeException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="scratchdir":Infa_Linux:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x)
Function [INFASQLGetDiagRecW] failed in adapter [/u01/app/informatica/plugins/dynamic/hiveruntime/libhive.so] with error code [100].
FnName: INFASQLExecute -- execute(). SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 12, cause: FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.RuntimeException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="scratchdir":Infa_Linux:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x)
Function [INFASQLGetDiagRecW] failed in adapter [/u01/app/informatica/plugins/dynamic/hiveruntime/libhive.so] with error code [100].].
```

But hive is working fine in command promt ? Any suggestions..

Comment: Make sure the user with which you are starting your thift/hive server is a HDFS user(it has access to create and delete directory in HDFS)

Answer (score 0):

First, please check if your hive thrift server is up and running .

It is advised to use the following command to start the hive thrift server

```
  hive --service hiveserver -p 10001
```

Telnet and check if the server is running in port 10001 , If yes I suppose your issue would be resolved